# uWSGI Error - Python application not found

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I am following [this](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/python-uwsgi/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin) instruction. I get the below error:

```
uWSGI Error - Python application not found
```

I use `uwsgi -x` the configuration xml to get more info:

```
  [WARNING] option "app" is deprecated: use the more advanced "mount" option
    *** Starting uWSGI 1.2.3-debian (32bit) on [Tue Feb 26 16:23:28 2013] ***
    compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 26 September 2012 07:58:38
    detected number of CPU cores: 1
    current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/apps-available
    detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
    limiting address space of processes...
    your process address space limit is 536870912 bytes (512 MB)
    your memory page size is 4096 bytes
     *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers ***
    detected max file descriptor number: 1024
    lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
    unlink(): Permission denied [socket.c line 75]
    bind(): Address already in use [socket.c line 107]
```

What is the possible error?

Thank you.

Comment: The `unlink()` and `bind()` lines suggest that you're trying to run nginx without root privileges.  you needs root privs (as root, sudo, etc) in order to bind to port 80.